# Entitymanager.persist is failing in Informix UDR

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, informix

I am unable to understand the reason of failure in UDR here:
while I am compiling the code on windows using Eclipse the programe is able to insert the record in informix DB residing on UNIX while same code is failing 
and throwing below Exception at run time when registering as UDR in same informix (11.50) DB on Unix (SunOS 5.10).
/* Surprise is that merge is working fine in both cases but persist fails */

Exception caught:

javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.lang.NullPointerException
Error Code: -79716
Call: INSERT INTO ....

My Code is:

```
public abstract class FXOPSDBAccess {
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if(emf == null){
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DALPOCService");
        }

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Session session = ((JpaEntityManager) em.getDelegate()).getSession();


        return em;
    }


public class CdaFeedDaoImpl extends FXOPSDBAccess implements CdaFeedDao  {

public void setListByWssctrlNo(CdaFeed cdafeedObj) {



        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
       try{
                EntityTransaction transct = em.getTransaction();
            transct.begin();
            em.persist(cdafeedObj);
           cdafeedObj.setTextField1("This is testing");
           transct.commit();
       }catch(Exception er){
           System.out.println("Exception in setListByWssctrlNo :  "+er);
           er.printStackTrace();

       }finally{
           em.close();
       }
     }
}




public static String checktlinkupdate(Integer tradeno)  {
        String wssControlNo="This is Test";
        List<CdaFeed> cdaFeedresult = new ArrayList<CdaFeed>();
        try{
            CdaFeedDao cdaFeedDao = (CdaFeedDao) FXOPSDaoFactory.getDAOImpl("CdaFeedDaoImpl");
            cdaFeedresult = cdaFeedDao.getListByTradeNo(tradeno.intValue());
            wssControlNo = cdaFeedresult.get(0).getWssControlno();
            if(cdaFeedresult != null){
                cdaFeedDao.setListByWssctrlNo(cdaFeedresult.get(0));
            }else{
                System.out.println("CdaFeed Object is NULL");
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wssControlNo;
    }
}

}
```

My UDR name is : checktlinkupdate

System.getProperty("java.version")

Answer (score 1):

The full stack trace and the SQL would help, but it seems to be hitting a bug in the driver.

You may wish the see if there is a patch from in the JDBC driver, or if you are using the correct driver for your database version.

Otherwise, identify what in the SQL is causing the error and try to workaround it.